# Implementing chat layout with UICollectionView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Is what I'm trying to accomplish here even possible? I've been searching for hours for sample code and/or SO answers that demonstrate this simply enough to follow, but so far no luck.

Goal: implement something that looks roughly like this mock:

[image: Tableview-ish layout with dynamic-height cells]

Yes, I know this is easy with a tableview, but the full design includes custom interactions, multiple columns, UIKit dynamics, and custom animations when adding/deleting cells, so UICollectionView is the better candidate. Until I can get this core layout to work, though, the rest of it is just a pipe dream.

So far I've started with a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that has a single label with constraints to all 4 sides of the content view. At which point I run into these issues:

1. It's unclear how I can calculate collectionViewContentSize() when the cells don't exist yet, esp. given that the majority of cells are actually offscreen most of the time!
2. If I just throw in an arbitrary content size (e.g., 320x1000), my views show up, but their heights don't adjust to the label content…I can't seem to read the cell height from within my UICollectionViewLayout subclass.

Seen or done anything like this? I'd include code, but after hours of futzing with it. I'm just looking for a clearer tutorial or sample code that fits this scenario.

Comment: add Textview instead of label and set UItextview height according to content size in it and implement the following collection view delegate                     (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

Comment: Thanks, Sachin. So far, it sounds like the answer is, "No, it's not possible to do this leveraging AutoLayout to get the cell sizes." Was really hoping not to have to manually calculate sizes as doing so slows down design iterations and is just generally a pain in the ass.

Comment: `[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]` will help you to determine the size for a cell. You will need to have a separate offscreen cell just for calculations.

Comment: heyy.. any useful tutorial you found out? Please do let me know..

Comment: @clozach Hi, did you find any solution for this. I'm in the need of some solution.

Comment: Wish I could help you, @Gurunathan, but sadly, no.

Answer (score 1):

There's a project you might want to look at. It's fairly involved and probably has a lot of code for situations that don't quite match yours, but does indeed create a chat view using a UICollectionView.

It can be found here: 
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

For item 1 - with regards to calculating collectionViewContentSize, I think you'll find you may not need to calculate that, at least as long as you're using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass for the layout.

And for item 2 - rather than set a fixed 320x1000 take a look at the JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.m for sizeItemAtIndexPath.

Sorry, this probably should have been a comment, but I lack the reputation to comment & so I made it an answer (doesn't that seem backwards? Ah well.)

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen this one before, but couldn't see the forest for the trees; there's a ton of structure there that I don't need, and, more to the point, it doesn't seem to use AutoLayout. :-\

Comment: Looks like a full blown VC, not very useful if you want something like a UIView.

Comment: Note that the project linked above is now deprecated.
There's others that have replaced it, but today my answer would probably be to just use generic UICollectionView, especially if it's a project you're going to be supporting for the long haul